# Rails - Id can't be found in Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Have some time I'm stuck in this problem. I'm trying to pass 3 Id's through a form to save the data in my database.

```
def new
  @person = Person.find(params[:person])
  @honored = Person.find(params[:honored])
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @honor = Honor.new
end

def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]),
           :person => Person.find(params[:person]),
           :honored => Person.find(params[:honored]))
 if @honor.valid?
  flash[:success] = "Honor created."
  redirect_to (:back)
 else
  redirect_to (:back)
 end
end
```

In my view where I call the `new` method:

```
<% @asked_groupmembership.each do |agm| %>
<%= link_to "Create Honor", new_honor_path(:group_id => @group.id, :person => current_person.id,
  :honored => agm.member.id) %>
```

My forms:

```
<% form_for @honor do |f| %>

 <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :person, :value => current_person.id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :honored, :value => @honored.id %>

 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :texto %><br />
<%= f.text_field :texto %>
 </div>
```

When I click the submit button I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Group without an ID

app/controllers/honors_controller.rb:22:in `create'

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"C7wofMY4VcyfdS10oc3iglex8nZVBMQ0Nh22nMiaOqs=",
 "honor"=>{"group_id"=>"39",
 "person"=>"2",
 "honored"=>"44",
 ...
                },
 "commit"=>"Insert"}
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

**##EDITED##**

```
class Honor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => "person_id"
  belongs_to :honored, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => "honored_id"
  belongs_to :group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => "group_id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your create method with:

```
def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.create(:group_id => params[:honor][:group],
           :person_id => params[:honor][:person],
           :honored_id => params[:honor][:honored])
 if @honor.save
 ...
end
```

Because after submitting your form you got your data in params[:honor]. You can see the hash passed to the controller in the code posted in your question:

```
"honor"=>{"group"=>"39",
 "person"=>"2",
 "honored"=>"44",
```

Comment: changed the answer... please take a look.

Comment: Thanks it worked, were all my mistakes with names, sorry!. But the things I pass in the form are going in blank, any idea?

Comment: I mean, when I check my database I have the ID's saved and the `honor` created, but everything in the forms goes `nil`.

Comment: If you execute in console the following code, you got the right record in db? Honor.create(:group_id => 3,
           :person_id => 2,
           :honored_id => 1)

Comment: Yes. And I also added my attributes as well and it saved all fine.

Comment: maybe you can try changing **if @honor.save** to **if @honor.valid**?

Comment: No success, even added `#` to the `if/else` lines but nothing changes :/

Comment: try to inspect the object after create using **logger.info @honor.inspect**

Comment: I don't known if it helps but checking the log in development I found that (my attributes are in portuguese so I won't translate): `INSERT INTO "honors" ("group_id", "person_id", "honor_id", "texto", "nota", "nivel_habilidade", "comprometimento", "tempo_demora", "criatividade", "organicazao", "comunicacao", "trabalho_grupo", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (39, 2, 44, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-05-26 12:58:56.433510', '2011-05-26 12:58:56.433510') RETURNING "id"`

Comment: it should work as expected... you can see that you are calling `INSERT INTO "honors" ("group_id", "person_id", "honor_id", ...) VALUES (39, 2, 44, ...)` that is the right call to record your values...

Comment: Edited the first part of the question and also put a field of my forms

Comment: Try to change `@honor.create` in `@honor.new` and `if @honor.valid?` in `if @honor.save`

Comment: Thanks for the long help provided, really thanks. I will accept your answer since you just did it perfect. I'm opening a new one to try discuss that matter at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139344/rails-weird-forms-not-saving-anything

Answer (score 0):

In order or make it a little more readable let's do this

Form:

```
<% form_for @honor do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :person_id, :value => current_person.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :honored_id, :value => @honored.id %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @person = Person.find(params[:person])
  @honored = Person.find(params[:honored])
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @honor = Honor.new
end

def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.create(
    :group => Group.find(params[:honor][:group_id]),
    :person => Person.find(params[:honor][:person_id]),
    :honored => Person.find(params[:honor][:honored_id])
  )

  if @honor.save
    ...
  end
end
```

Every hidden field inside the form will reach the controller as a param inside the `params[:honor]`

Now, taking a look at the controller there's something that doesn't look quite right. The `create` method will create a new instance and save the object if there are no errors. Calling `create` and then `save` will work but you can either call `new` (instead of `create`) and then `save` or just keep using `create` and then `valid?`. Personally I think that the `new` then `save` process is cleaner.

Example:

```
def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.new(
    :group => Group.find(params[:honor][:group_id]),
    :person => Person.find(params[:honor][:person_id]),
    :honored => Person.find(params[:honor][:honored_id])
  )

  if @honor.save
    ...
  end
end
```