# Rails - Forms acting Weird: not saving any text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

After getting my question solved by Matteo Alessani in [Rails - Id can't be found in Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138153/rails-id-cant-be-found-in-forms), I noticed that my form isn't saving the fields I pass.

I will copy here all the piece of code I have from the other question:

Routes:

```
resources :honors
```

Model:

```
class Honor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => "person_id"
  belongs_to :honored, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => "honored_id"
  belongs_to :group, :class_name => 'Group', :foreign_key => "group_id"
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @person = Person.find(params[:person])
  @honored = Person.find(params[:honored])
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @honor = Honor.new
end


def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.save(:group_id => params[:honor][:group],
           :person_id => params[:honor][:person],
           :honored_id => params[:honor][:honored])
if @honor.valid?
  flash[:success] = "Honor created."
  redirect_to (:back)
 else
  redirect_to (:back)
 end
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @asked_groupmembership.each do |agm| %>
<%= link_to "Create Honor", new_honor_path(:group_id => @group.id,
 :person => current_person.id, :honored => agm.member.id) %>
```

My Forms:

```
<% form_for @honor do |f| %>

 <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :person, :value => current_person.id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :honored, :value => @honored.id %>

 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :texto %><br />
<%= f.text_field :texto %>
 </div>
```

And the error is that I can get the ID's from `group` and `person` and the `honored` one, but nothing that I type in the forms (my attributes are in portuguese so I won't translate):

```
 INSERT INTO "honors" ("group_id", "person_id", "honor_id", "texto", "nota", 
 "nivel_habilidade", "comprometimento", "tempo_demora",
 "criatividade", "organicazao", "comunicacao", "trabalho_grupo", "created_at",
 "updated_at") VALUES (39, 2, 44, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
 NULL, NULL, '2011-05-26 12:58:56.433510', '2011-05-26 12:58:56.433510')
 RETURNING "id".
```

Note: the Parameters in log are with the values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistake in controller

```
def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor  = Honor.new(params[:honor])
  if @honor.save
    flash[:success] = "Honor created."
    redirect_to (:back)
  else
    redirect_to (:back)
  end
end
```

Comment: I got an even weird error. I will add a piece I forgot on the code that shows my newcall. The error is: `Group(#35572728) expected, got String(#3110088)  app/controllers/honors_controller.rb:25:in 'new'
app/controllers/honors_controller.rb:25:in 'create'`

Comment: Hello. It's `@honor  = Honor.new(params[:honor])`

Comment: In form view 
`<%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :person_id, :value => current_person.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :honored_id, :value => @honored.id %>`

:person to :person_id, :honored to :honored_id